# How avoid zurb founction styles from overriding jqgrid/jquery ui styles?

Tags: css, jqgrid, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation CSS framework and jqGrid to display data, but Foundation styles are messing with jqGrid/jquery UI styles...

I've tried a lot of changes and search, but I can't figure out how to do it...

Here is an example : http://jsbin.com/cocukube/1/
I would like the jqGrid to be displayed like that : http://jsbin.com/cocukube/2/
But of course, with all Foundation styles...

Thank you very much.

Comment: I managed to override some of the foundation styles : http://jsbin.com/cocukube/4/ with this CSS : http://test.thebishop.fr/jqgrid/css/custom.css, but some glitches remain : filter fields are too low in the cell and the white block in under the Notes title... if anyone have a clue, thanks !!!

Comment: I would recommend you to add `.ui-jqgrid table thead tr th, table thead tr td, table tfoot tr th, table tfoot tr td { padding: 0 }`

Comment: Thank you, it's much better. Now I still have this white cell remaining.

Comment: What do you mean? Where is the demo with the last changes? It can be that you need include more settings for `<select>` and `<input>` inside of jqGrid. Something like `.ui-jqgrid input, .ui-jqgrid select { padding: 0, height: auto; width: auto; line-height: inherit; }`. Probably one have to specify more long CSS rule. All depends on the corresponding CSS rule used in Foundation CSS. So the demo is really required.

Comment: The latest demo has been updated : http://jsbin.com/cocukube/4

Comment: This "white cell" always an only occurs in the last column...

Comment: Well, I noticed the text in the last header cell is slightly higher than other header cells.
Above <th> is also really thin as you can see in this picture :
http://cjoint.com/14av/DDljZimG5Vt.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would begin by taking a look at the order in which you're loading the CSS. In order to assure that Foundation is not overriding your jqGrid styles, make sure that jqGrid is being loaded after Foundation.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foundation.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqgrid.css">
```

If that's not the issue, you might need to create an override.css file to essentially "undo" some of the styles that Foundation is applying. If this is necessary, make sure that your override.css file is called after the other two.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, "jqgrid.css" is already called after "foundation.css". I already tried to override some styles with !important but without any changes... I'm looking for a way to do that a bit less specific :(